# Transpose a list of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Given the following list of dictionaries representing a dataset:

```
a = [{"animal":"dog", "age":2},{"animal": "duck", "age": "3"}, {"animal": "duck", "age": "5"},{"animal":"dog", "age":10}]
```

How can I transpose this row-wise representation to the following column-wise representation:

```
b = {"animal":["dog","duck","duck","dog"],"age":[2,3,5,10]}
```

The only way that I am seeing to do this is not efficient - from the first entry extract the keys and then for each key iterate over the rows to extract the values.

Do you know a better way of doing this?

Comment: why do you consider this "not efficient"? What you describe makes sense. It scales linearly with it's input, any approach that would result in `b` would have to.

Comment: Since I am not using any pre-built python function and  a 2 step approach (1st extract keys and then a for inside a for). when I implemented this, it seemed to me that there could be room for improvement.

Comment: But what is your criteria for efficiency, exactly? Room for improvement of *what*?

Comment: As you said this scales linearly, so my critera its just time. There could a different way that could explore the memory position of the elements to quickly perform this operation.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are expecting, there is no way to do this without visiting every key-value pair of every dictionary in your list. You will not beat a linear time complexity. There is no built-in function that does this, but you could write a C-extension that pushes the looping down into the C layer (which is what the advantage of a built-in function would be). If you showed us your existing approahc, there may be more *idiomatic* ways, but if it works as you describe, probably no more efficient approach.

Comment: how big is actually your list `a`? and what is an acceptable timing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely what you're describing, but I see this as a perfectly reasonable approach, making use of a [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to initialize values in `b` to empty lists:

```
from collections import defaultdict
b = defaultdict(list)
for animal in a:
    for key, val in animal.items():
        b[key].append(val)
print(b)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'animal': ['dog', 'duck', 'duck', 'dog'], 'age': [2, '3', '5', 10]})
```

Comment: without collections `b.setdefault(key,[]).append(val)`

Answer (score 1):

```
keys = a[0].keys() if len(a) > 0 else []
vals = zip(*map(lambda x: x.values(), a))
b = dict(zip(keys, vals)))
```